# Giving a unique ID on create new row for the kendo grid in the JS

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid.. It works fine.. But when I create a new row in the grid I need to provide a unique ID (integer is fine but not a duplicate one eg. 0, 1, 2, 3.. ) to save. At the moment when I get data from backend I count the number of rows and keep it in the session. And when an user requests for new row, I read the session and find the number of rows there and add 1 to create a unique ID. Is there any elegant way of giving a unique ID for the grid in the JS without using the session. Thanks in advance.

```
$("#TrainingDetailsGrid").kendoGrid({

    dataSource: {

        transport: {

            read: {
                url: "GetTrainingDetailsData",
                datatype: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json"
            },
            create: {
                url: "UpdateTrainingDetailsData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            update: {
                url: "UpdateTrainingDetailsData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                if (operation != "read") {                                       
                    return kendo.stringify(data.models);
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 5,
        serverPaging: false,
        batch: true,

        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "ID",
                fields: {
                    ID: { editable: false },
                    Description: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                    Instructor: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: { message: "Instructor name is required" } } },
                    Trainee: { editable: true },
                    TimeSpent: { editable: true, type: "number", validation: { required: { message: "Hours are required" }, min: 0, step: 0.25 } },
                }
            },
            errors: "Errors"
        },

        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.errors + "TrainingDetailsGrid");
        }
    },
    groupable: false,
    autoBind: false,
    sortable: true,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    editable: "inline",
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true
    },
    dataBound: onDataBound,

    columns:
        [
            { field: "Description", width: 90, title: "Description" },
            { field: "Instructor", width: 90, title: "Instructor" },
            { field: "Trainee", width: 90, title: "Trainee" },
            { field: "TimeSpent", width: 90, title: "Hours" },
            { command: ["edit"], title: "Action", width: "175px" }
        ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parameterMap you can count the number of rows you have in the Grid and put the value in the model before you pass it to the server side.

```
parameterMap: function (data, operation) 
{
  if (operation != "read") {
    if (operation == "create") {
      if ($("#TrainingDetailsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total() > 0) {  
        data.models[0].ID = $("#TrainingDetailsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total() - 1;
        }
      else {
        data.models[0].ID = 0;
      }
    }
    return kendo.stringify(data.models);
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if I can remove an item and then add another one? Won't two items in the datasource have the same ID?

Comment: Yes it will be if you think about DB; according to the question they were used to count rows. That means its not related with the DB instead they count and give ids for the rows. This solution is not flawless, if you have 4 rows (id 0, 1, 2, 3) if you delete row 3 and then create a new row, row 3 and 4 will have same id 3, you are correct. For the scenario they've given it worked; but not 100% correct solution I have to admit.